# How can I ensure that a function never gets executed concurrently in perl?

Tags: perl

I use Mojo::IOLoop to talk to a port to send commands to a digital receiver.

Because the receiver can only open the port once, but the code talking to it sits behind a web interface and a web server, there is a risk that commands get sent concurrently - so the digital receiver loses them, and things go wrong.

So - how can I ensure that some piece of code never gets run concurrently?

I was trying to use file locks like this:

```
sub enqueue {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($cmd, $promise) = @_;

    while (!(flock DATA, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) { sleep(0.25) }

    my (@r);

    my $id = Mojo::IOLoop->client({ address => '192.168.1.204', 
                                    port => 23, timeout => 13 }
              => sub ($loop, $err, $stream) {
                  return $promise->reject('could not open stream') unless $stream;

                  $stream->on(error => sub ($stream, $err) {
                                  flock(DATA, LOCK_UN);
                                  $stream->close;
                                  $promise->reject($err);
                              });

                  $stream->on(read => sub ($stream, $bytes) {
                                  $bytes =~ s/\r\n$//;
                                  push @r, split /\r\n/, $bytes;
                                  # stream done is a function that checks that 
                                  # the appropriate number of lines got sent back
                                  if (stream_done(@r)) {
                                      flock(DATA, LOCK_UN);
                                      $promise->resolve(\@r);
                                      $stream->close;
                                  };
                              });

                  $stream->on(timeout => sub ($stream) {
                                  flock(DATA, LOCK_UN);
                                  $stream->close;
                                  $promise->reject('timeout') if ($err);
                              });
                  $stream->write($cmd);
              });
}
```

Comment: I'd re-engineer the problem so there's only ever one thing that talks to the receiver. The web processes talk to that one thing, which, since it is the only thing talking to the receiver, doesn't have to coordinate with anyone. Think about how syslog works, for example.

Comment: @briandfoy - so I've been thinkig about that, but got a stuck between a rock and a hard place. Because of the way the response comes back from the receiver, I only managed to make it work via Mojo::IOLoop, which is async, and therefore makes it hard to avoid concurrency. I also attempted to do this with a queue, but got completely tangled up. Probably getting my architecture wrong - which is not surprising given that I'm not a pro, and this is my first attempt at (relatively) low level networking protocols

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want to do as I am not familiar with Mojo. But if you just don't want to execute a function two times create a lock file and delete if when it is finished:

```perl
use File::Slurp;
sub my_method_to_execute_only_once {
    my $tmp = 'temp.txt';
    return if (is_method_running($tmp));
    # DO YOUR STUFF
    unlink $tmp;
}
sub is_method_running{
    
    my ($filename) = @_;
    
    if (-e $tmp){
        return 1; 
    }
    
    write_file($tmp, "running");
    return 0;
}
```